# not able to send email from PHP page

Tags: php, html, html-email

I want to send email from contact page of the my site. I google and it told to use PHP scripts as my domain is LINUX based so I cannot use ASP. I tried couple of them but not able to send. How ever I have used @ECHO to display message, which I got but not the email. Here the codes that I tried:

```
<?php 

 $userid='to.useri@example.com';
 $subject='New Requirement';

 $Name=$_POST['Name'];
 $Email=$_POST['Email'];
 $Phone=$_POST['Phone'];    
 $Message=$_POST['Message'];

 $body= <<<EOD;
 <br><hr><br>
 Name: $Name <br>
 Email: $Email <br>
 Phone:  $From <br> 
 Message: $Message
EOD;
  $headers='From: $Email';
  mail($userid,$subject,$body,$headers);
  echo "Message send!!!";
?>
```

And I also tried :

```
<?php
 $to      = 'to.user@example.com';
 $subject = 'the subject';
  $message = 'hello';
  $headers = 'From: from.user@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: from.user@example.com' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers )) {
ECHO 'Message send successfully';
} 
else {
ECHO 'Please try again, Message could not be sent!';
}  
?>
```

Can any one tell me what am I missing here.

Comment: If those email address are real, please replace them with dummy ones.

Comment: Is mail enabled on your PHP server?

Comment: Are you on RedHat (Centos)? Because there is a Selinux Rule that will prevent Apache to send mails. Check that the `httpd_can_sendmail` bool is set to true.

Comment: @JayBlanchard how to check if mail is enabled?

Comment: There are a number of ways but you can start with running phpinfo in a page and searching for mail services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your if Condition with the below mentioned code, hope it works:-

```
      $mail=mail($to, "Subject: $subject",$message );
       if($mail){
       echo "Thank you for using our mail form";
     }else{
   echo "Mail sending failed."; 
 }
```

Comment: succesful or not ? didn't got u?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$senderName="John";
$senderEmail= "test@domain.com";
$recipient = "recipient@domain.com";
$subject ="testmail";
$message="test message";


$headers = "From: " . $senderName . " <" . $senderEmail . ">";

$success = mail($recipient, $subject, $message, $headers );
```

Comment: just use your domain name in $senderEmail then try it.